# Dictionary - Object referenced not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

I'm trying to hold a lobby system inside of a dictionary.

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> lobbys;
```

The first string being the Lobby ID, and the dictionary within the dictionary holding the clients usernames in the lobby.

When I try to create a new 'lobby' in the dictionary like so:

```
lobbys.Add("dSd244SfasdD", null);
```

( the "dSd244SfasdD" being the unique lobby ID, and null being the null dictionary I've yet to create (since theres no users in it yet))

I get this error: "Object referenced not set to an instance of an object."

I'm unsure as to what I'm doing wrong, and I'm fairly new to C#. Please help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must first instantiate the lobbys Dictionary (which holds the Dictionaries):

```
lobbys = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

Then you can add to this lobbys, and when you do so, you should instantiate those inner dictionaries.

```
lobbys.Add("dsD244SfasD", new Dictionary<string, string>());
```

Then, when you add to those inner dictionaries:

```
lobbys["dsD244fasD"].Add("Client1", "Bob Jones");
lobbys["dsD244fasD"].Add("Client2", "Bill James");
```

Answer (score 4):

You **need to [instantiate](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/instantiationI06232007000158AM/instantiationI.aspx)** your dictionary.

```
lobbys = new  Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>();
```

If its a field in your class, you can initialize it at Field or you can initialize it in the class constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't assigned a value to your variable, so it's got the default value of null. (Don't forget that the value of `lobbys` isn't an object - it's a *reference*). You could either assign it a value in your constructor, or in the declaration:

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> lobbys
    = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

(You may well want to make it a `readonly` variable at the same time - that wouldn't stop you from changing the dictionary's contents, but it would mean that the variable would always refer to the *same* dictionary.)

Answer (score 1):

You need create an instance of the object first before use it.

```
 private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> lobbys = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> lobbys
    = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```